# Connection Refused: Dockerized Spring Boot Application Unable to Connect to Local PostgreSQL Database

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm encountering an issue while trying to connect a Spring Boot application running in a Docker container to a local PostgreSQL database on my host machine. In my application.properties file, I'm attempting to connect to the database using localhost:5432 (i should use localhost), but I'm getting a "Connection refused" error.

Here's my application.properties configuration:

```
main.jdbc.url.primary=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app
main.jdbc.username=postgres
main.jdbc.password=admin
```

in my docker compose i added network_mode: host but i had Connection to localhost:5432 refused. my docker compose is:

```
version: '3'

services:   app:
    image: 'docker-app:latest'
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: app
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
```

I'm not sure why the connection to localhost:5432 is being refused. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your database is not running on `localhost` (that would mean "in the same container as your application"). It is running on your host machine. There are a number of questions here on stackoverflow that deal with this situation.

Comment: That's why i added network_mode host but the problem does not been resolved